# Install 32-bit JDK on Natty 64-bit, I

Tags: 32bit-64bit, java, ubuntu-11.04

I want to install Oracle's JDK (32 bit version) under Ubuntu Natty (64 bit version). While there is a package for JRE (32 bit version), I want JDK (32 bit version).

I want to avoid the installer provided with the .bin file, and rather use a .deb file. However, it seems the package java-helper has disappeared in Natty. What can I do?

Comment: This question belongs on http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 1):

The Java compiler produces byte code which is same whether you use the 32-bit or 64-bit JDK and plan to use the 32-bit or 64-bit JRE.

The bit-ness of the JDK and JRE don't have to be the same and its unlikely you will notice the difference. (The maximum memory is possibly the main one)

Comment: Let's say I want to use Eclipse: It complains about not having a JDK when I select the package for JRE (32 bit version) using update-alternatives.

Comment: @A.M. So what happen when you give it a JDK (which is for development) instead of a JRE (which is not for development)

Answer (score 0):

The JDK installation can be treated as 'zip' installation, which means that the installer simply unzips the content of jdk to the target directory on your machine. You can try to copy-paste the required jdk directory to your machine and probably set JAVA_HOME variable if needed. The above should do the magic.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you, but that does not solve Debian package management integration (update-alternatives and the like), which I want to have.

Comment: I fail to recognize the correlation between the JDK installation and the Debian package management.

Comment: AFAIK you take care of the package management by installing additional tools (APT) which has nothing to do with Oracle JDK. So in order to get fully functional JDK you need simply copy it to you target machine, then run sudo apt-get install gcl (if you know how to operate with PM tools like APT) otherwise, follow the instructions here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-lpic1-v3-102-4/?ca=drs- BTW: weren't you refering to Ubuntu in your question and not to Debian? Ubuntu has RPM which helps you to manage packages. Open new threads for issues not related to JDK.